# SSIS Failing while setting datetime value

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ssis, date-formatting

I have two servers. Both of them are running with Regions and Language with DateTime formats in German `dd.mm.yyyy`

I deployed a SSIS package which uses a datetime parameter and while one of the servers accepts the format `dd.mm.yyyy` the other one doesn't.

The parameter value is set like this:

```
SELECT @ssis_command = @ssis_command + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[User::business_ts].Properties[Value]\"";"\"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETUTCDATE(), 104) + ' ' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETUTCDATE(), 114)), 5, 46)) + '\"" '

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETUTCDATE(), 104) + ' ' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETUTCDATE(), 114)), 5, 46))
```

So I get a datetime in the following format: `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss`  but the second server expects the british/french format: `mm/dd//yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Both Servers have the English version of SQL Server.

Output for `DBCC USEROPTIONS` is exactly the same in both servers.

```
textsize    2147483647
language    us_english
dateformat  mdy
datefirst   7
lock_timeout    -1
quoted_identifier   SET
arithabort  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET
ansi_warnings   SET
ansi_padding    SET
ansi_nulls  SET
concat_null_yields_null SET
isolation level read committed
```

`Locale Id` of the SSIS Package is set to Germany

Any idea about what could be wrong in the server which expects a British date format? Is there any default date format for SQL Server Integration Services?

**Windows Server 2016**

**SQLServer 2017**

***EDIT:***
Here a screenshot with the properties window of SSIS package IDE. On design it is `dd.mm.yyyy` format with German (Germany) LocaleID, but in the XML view it displays the mm/dd/yyyy format.
[image]

[image]

```
<DTS:Variable
  DTS:CreationName=""
  DTS:Description="Timestamp for validity. (send to the package at ignition)"
  DTS:DTSID="{4D953920-D7BA-46E8-9683-45FDEE817661}"
  DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
  DTS:Namespace="User"
  DTS:ObjectName="business_ts">
  <DTS:VariableValue
    DTS:DataType="7">1/1/1950</DTS:VariableValue>
</DTS:Variable>
```

Comment: what u mean by server expects formats?. At table level or database level ?

Comment: when I run the SSIS package it fails trying to pass the parameter with the format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss` and only runs when `dd/mm/yyyy`...